# Kotlin Get properties from generic type

Tags: generics, kotlin, reflection

I can do something like this in C#

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties()
```

How to do the same in Kotlin

Comment: by property you meant KClass reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well JVM suffers from type-erasure at Runtime.

You cannot do that simply, but Kotlin provides `reified` keywords for `inline` functions to take advantage of

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T: Any> takeKClass() {
    val reflection: KClass<T> = T::class
    ...
}
```

But keep in mind that inline functions are embedded into call-site at compilation, but however this is a good feature provided by Kotlin.

Comment: Oh, thank you for answer. One more question. Is it posible to create new instance of generic type in Kotlin? Something like this in C#:
public T GetInstance()
    {
        return new T();
    }

Comment: @Michal yup there is https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-instance.html